# Using :before and :after on links without making the content part of the link

Tags: html, css

If I have the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/vQyZc/)

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Section</a>
    <a href="#">Subsection</a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
a:before {
    content: "/";
    padding-right: 4px;
}
a:first-child:before {
    content: "»";
}
```

the content separators show up as part of the link.

[image: what it looks like]

Any way for the content to not be part of the link and still use this css technique?

Comment: That HTML should probably be `<ul><li><a href="#">Home</a></li> .. </ul>`, and then you can use `li:before`.

Comment: @thirtydot: yes this is my idea too, i think there is not any other way.

Comment: it seems there is another way with "pointer-events"...

Comment: @thirtydot that seems to be the best way. want to submit as answer so i can accept

Comment: @qntmfred I did in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest changing your HTML to:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then you can use `li:before`:

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
li:before {
    content: "/";
    padding-right: 4px;
}
li:first-child:before {
    content: "»";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/vQyZc/5/

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with some change in your html code like this:

```
<p>
<span><a href="#">Home</a></span>
<span> <a href="#">Section</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Subsection</a></span>
</p>
```

and css like this:

```
span:before {
    content: "/";
    padding-right: 4px;
}
span:first-child:before {
    content: "»";
}
```

this is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v2km4/)